# Initializing member class with derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

So I'm trying to find the best practice way to have member classes be constructed to on of their derived classes.

```
struct A {
    int a = 0
}

struct B : struct A {
    int b = 0;
}
class ContainingClassA {
    ContainingClassA() : member_A(){}

    virtual A get() {
        return member_A;
    }

    A member_A;
}

class ContainingClassB : public ContainingClassA {
    ContainingClassB(){}

    virtual B get() override{
        return member_A;
    }
}
```

Is there a way of initializing `member_A` in class `ContainingClassB` such that it is of type B? I've seen perhaps adding a contructor to `ContainingClassA` in order to initialize `member_A`. I know i could just declare a `B member_B` variable in `ContainingClassB` and return it, but since `B` is derived from `A` it seems like I could somehow store it in the inherited variable `member_A`...

Comment: You've got it backwards.  `B` contains a `A` part.  `A` has no knowledge of or storage for `B`

Comment: @NathanOliver ah, ofcourse. I'm curious though, what if instead of storing the instance itself if I were storing a pointer to those classes?

Comment: consider having a Pointer in base Class, i.e. `A* memberA;` You can assign a B instance to it in ClassContainingB;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way of initializing `member_A` in class `ContainingClassB` such that it is of type B?

No. `member_A` is a member of `ContainingClassA`. `ContainingClassB` uses the *same* `member_A` from its parent class, `ContainingClassA`. You can't change the layout of the parent class.

Also you can't change the declaration of a virtual function (with a few exceptions). In other words, you can't override `A get()` with `B get()`.

You could change `get()` to return a *reference* instead, then it will be possible to override `A& get()` with `B& get()` (as `A&` and `B&` are covariant types).

But first you need to split the solution up into an "interface" and two "implementations" for A and B:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int a = 0;
};

struct B : public A {
    int b = 1;
};

class ContainingClassBase {
public:
    virtual const A& get() = 0;
};

class ContainingClassA : public ContainingClassBase {
    A member_A;
public:
    virtual const A& get() override { return member_A; }
};

class ContainingClassB : public ContainingClassBase {
    B member_B;
public:
    virtual const B& get() override { return member_B; }
};

int main() {
    ContainingClassA a;
    ContainingClassB b;
    std::cout << a.get().a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.get().b << std::endl;
}
```

---

Note also that a solution with allocating `A` separately and storing a pointer to it isn't very efficient because it's hard to avoid allocating a spurious `A` while constructing `ContainingClassB` (the constructor of `ContainingClassA` will still be invoked first).

Comment: There are a few specific ways you are allowed to change the return type of a function override: `const A& get()` and `const B& get()` or `const A* get()` and `const B* get()` would be valid cases of this "covariant return type".

Answer (score -1):

You could use templates to be able to choose the type of the variable. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  int a = 0;
};

struct B : A
{
  int b = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class ContainingClassA
{
 public:
  ContainingClassA() : member_A(){}

  virtual T get() {
    return member_A;
  }

  T member_A;
};

class ContainingClassB : public ContainingClassA<B>
{
 public:
  ContainingClassB() { }

  virtual B get() override
  {
    return member_A;
  }
};

int main()
{
  ContainingClassB cb;
  std::cout << cb.get().a;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << cb.get().b;
  return 0;
}
```